# OpenCV build method v/s pip install opencv-contrib-python

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I built a ubuntu 16.04 machine.

pip install opencv-contrib-python was fast.

That begs a question what am i missing for not having built OpenCV from the repository? I was planning to use OpenCV only in python.

Can someone advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My apologies folks:
I found my answer that **I am not missing anything by not building OpenCV from the repository**:

Q: Do I need to install also OpenCV separately?

A: No, the packages are special wheel binary packages and they already contain statically built OpenCV binaries.